# Form Data in not inserting in Mysql database In Express

Tags: mysql, express

Hello I am working React project And in want to insert form data to my mysql database. i had completed my backend code and for testing purpose i used postman. but i encountered an error in sql.

I searched for other similar question, but none of them is my type.

The error is

```
  sql: 'insert into employee (name,company,email,phone,location,photo,address,password,cpassword) values (NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);'
}
```

I I can't figure out where i am getting wrong.

**I inserted the data like this**

```
{
    "name" :"coc",
    "company":"accenture",
    "email" : "hello@gmail.com",
    "phone":"95072",
    "location":"kolkta",
    "photo":"file",
    "address":"boo",
    "password":"admin",
    "cpassword":"admin"
}
```

**my backend code**

```
app.post("/registerUser",(req,res)=>{
    const {name,comapny,email,phone,location,photo,address,password,cpassword} = req.body
    const registerUser = `insert into employee (name,company,email,phone,location,photo,address,password,cpassword) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);`
    db.query(registerUser,[name,comapny,email,phone,location,photo,address,password,cpassword],(err,doc)=>{
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        else{
            res.json(doc)
        }
    })

})
```

Thankyou

Comment: Before you go any further you should really read up on `async` and `await` to help de-nest code like this. Callback driven code is *extremely* frustrating to work with.

Comment: It looks like you failed to capture the parameters correctly, so check `req.body` first. Maybe you need a body parser that matches the type of data you're passing in?